# How can I present my main TabBar controller from the App Delegate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm really stuck with this issue and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction...

I'm building an iOS application with a Tab bar for the main navigation.

Users need to sign up/sign in before they can see the main screens and tab bar though.

Users can both sign in and sign up using Facebook connect.

The app communicates with our own API.

Currently... when the UITabBarController's initial view is loaded, it will check if there is a current user present and, if not, will present the sign in screen.

```
if (sessionID == (id)[NSNull null] || sessionID.length == 0){
    NSLog(@"session ID was null");
    SHOW_SIGN_IN_SCREEN;
}

#define SHOW_SIGN_IN_SCREEN SignInController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignInScreen"];\
[self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

From the Sign In Screen... the user can touch the "Sign in with Facebook" button or create a new account which segues to the Sign **Up** Screen. The sign up screen has a form for the user to fill out or alternatively they can tap the "Sign up with Facebook" button to create an account using their Facebook details provided by the Facebook graph.

The Facebook callbacks are all handled by the app delegate which is where I'm getting stuck.

The API doesn't care if the user credentials sent from the App are for a new user or an existing user. In either case, the API will return a valid session ID for the app to proceed.

Once the API has responded, the app delegate should then segue the user back to the main tab bar view controller which is where I'm stuck.

At the moment, I have this in the AppDelegate

```
// app delegate
-(void)segueToMainTabController
{
    NSLog(@"segueToMainTabController");
    SignInController *controller = (SignInController *)[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController];
    [controller segueToWelcomeScreen];
}

// sign in controller 
-(void)segueToWelcomeScreen
{
    NSLog(@"segueToWelcomeScreen");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SignInToMainTabBar" sender:self];
}
```

Which *is* being called but is not performing the segue...

Can anyone advise why this segue is not being performed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have an app where I need to hijack the initial view in my AppDelegate, so maybe you could do something similar. Using your condition, maybe try putting something like this in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
if (sessionID == (id)[NSNull null] || sessionID.length == 0){
    // whatever you need to do to initialize for the login screen
    // you should make the login view the initial view in your storyboard
}
else { // hijack the initial view to show the tab bar   
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
    MyTabViewController *tabViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyTabViewController"];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Hope that helps.